# Mule 4 : Batch Processing : Can we set Aggregator size more than Batch block size?

Tags: mule4

Scenario :

- processing data of huge volume say 1 million records
- each record is of 1MB in size
- using batch processing to process these records where block size is set as 100
- I have to aggregate the elements in an Aggregator and then call an external API to write these data.
- I can only make n calls to the api in 1 hour.
  So I am calculating aggregator size as follows :

aggregator_size = total_number_of_records/n

Thus, aggregator_size >> batch block size.

So is it a right approach?
What alternative can be done for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Block size is the number of records that are going to be read by each batch thread to process.

[Aggregator size](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/batch-filters-and-batch-aggregator#aggregating-records-using-a-fixed-size) is the number of records that are going to be aggregated in an aggregator inside a step, if not [using streaming](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/batch-filters-and-batch-aggregator#streaming-records-in-a-batch-aggregator). Note that using streaming you can only access the aggregated records sequentially, but memory usage is lower.

For the scenario described also take into account that if you are going to write to the same file, there might be issues because several batch threads may try to write to the same file at the same time, corrupting it, or the order of writing can be unpredictable.